# Enforce type checking for object created by spreading

Tags: typescript

If we compose an object by spreading 2 different types of objects, then TypeScript does not do the type-checking. How to enforce TypeScript to do the checking?

```
type TypeA = {
    id: number;
}

type TypeB = {
    name: string;
}

const a: TypeA = { id: 3 };
const b: TypeB = { name: 'my' };

const c: TypeA = {
    ...a,
    ...b,
};
```

Variable `c` has type `TypeA`, but should complain that `name` is not in the type definition. However, it does not:

[image]

While if given a non-existing field explicitly, TypeScript complains as expected:

[image]

Comment: _Excess property checks_ only apply in certain circumstances. `c.name` isn't accessible via `TypeA` anyway, what's the problem?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. But TypeScript should put a warning when it tries to assign `name` to `c` right? If I run `console.log(JSON.stringify(c));`, actually it gives `"{"id":3,"name":"my"}" `. That's not compatible with `TypeA`

Comment: It _is_ compatible with `TypeA` - it has an `id` property with `number`-type value. TypeScript is _structurally_, not _nominally_, typed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But when giving a non-existing field `new`, it gives warning. That's more reasonable. This actually brings us some hidden bugs. If there is some linting rule to enforce this checking, it will definitely help us.

Comment: ...because that _is_ one of the circumstances excess property checks are applied in, when the property is actually _in_ the object literal. Because that property doesn't exist anywhere _outside_ something that's supposed to be `TypeA` it's obviously a mistake to include it.

Comment: That's a mistake indeed. So we rely on TypeScript to capture the mistake, a warning or error. Then we can avoid the mistake. And it looks like TypeScript should be able to pinpoint the type mismatch.

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have so-called *exact types* as requested in [ms/TS#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), and excess property checking isn't really meant to provide them.  There are no config options you can set to give this to you.  You can work around it with generic helper functions, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaEQEN).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Great thanks @jcalz. Please help to write up an anwser and i will accept it. This is definitely what I am looking for.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance, probably after I get some sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript are *open* or *extendible* and not *closed* or *exact*.  A type like `interface Foo {a: string}` means that a value must have a `string`-valued `a` property, but it doesn't prohibit other properties.  That allows you to write `interface Bar extends Foo {b: number}` and it means that every `Bar` is also a `Foo`.  This means that interface and class hierarchies are also *type* hierarchies.  In your example, `c` is a valid `TypeA`, so there is no error.

Sometimes people really want exact types, as requested in longstanding open issue [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  Such types would say that, while `Bar` is assignable to `Foo`, it is not assignable to `Exact<Foo>`, because an `Exact<Foo>` is not allowed to have any property other than `a`.  But for now there is no direct support for this.

---

TypeScript *does* have so-called [excess property warnings for object literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), where the compiler will mark as an error if you add an unexpected property directly into an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).  If I wrote `const foo: Foo = {a: "abc", z: true}`, the compiler would warn on `z`.  This is similar to what would happen if `Foo` were exact.  **But excess property warnings are not really meant to provide exact types**.  The reason `const foo: Foo = {a: "abc", z: true}` is flagged is that by [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `foo` as `Foo`, the only thing the compiler will remember about that object is that it is a `Foo`; the `z` property will be forgotten and thus inaccessible, and that's probably a mistake.

And such a mistake goes away with `const baz = {a: "abc", z: true}; const foo: Foo = baz;` Now `baz` knows about `z`, so it's not a big deal that `foo` has forgotten about it.  So there's no warning now.

In your example, the `name` property of `c` is remembered by `b`, so there is no warning.

By analogy: exact types would be like a bus company prohibiting passengers from bringing food onto the bus, while excess property warnings would be like a bus company prohibiting passengers from leaving food on the bus.  Both bus companies would scold you for leaving a sandwich on the seat, but for different reasons.

---

So, if there are no exact types in TypeScript, what can you do instead?

Inside microsoft/TypeScript#12936 some workarounds are mentioned, such as [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-368244671) suggesting the use of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function which compares a value to an "exactified" version of the type you care about, by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the excess properties of the value to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  Like this:

```
const exactly = <T extends object,>() =>
  <U extends T & { [P in Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>]: never }>(
    u: U): T => u;

const exactlyTypeA = exactly<TypeA>();
```

Now the `exactlyTypeA()` function will only accept values which are "exactly" `A`, at least to the extent the compiler knows (since you can write `const v = {id: 1, xxx: 2}` and then `const a: A = v`, then `a` has an extra property that the compiler doesn't know about, and nothing will prevent that from happening.  All this means is that you'd better use `exactlyTypeA()` on values as early as possible and don't let them get widened to `A` before you do):

```
const c = exactlyTypeA({
  ...a,
  ...b,
}); // error! Types of property 'name' are incompatible.

const d = exactlyTypeA({
  ...a
}) // okay
```

Looks good.  There's an error in `c` because `{...a, ...b}` has more properties than `A`, while `d` is fine because `{...a}` does not.

Again, this isn't perfect, since it can be circumvented, and because it requires more boilerplate code, but in the absence of true exact types, it's probably close to the best you can do.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8BQUoEsAmAXFAHYCuAtgEYQBOA3BgL4YaiSzwBCK6WJAhuQhEAzsBo5iAcwbMMAYwD2xMVH5E4kJKjS5CUAMxRGDJSuBRKGrj13FBwqAHJyIJ8YYLlqiAA9+8sAANiA8ADwwUH7AEMR4IlCKlABWEIEANAB8ABQAlCiZfGEAqlG+MXEJkQBk6FAA2gAKuMRQAKK+8kGkeBBhANYQIIoAZlDF6VCDw2MwmQC6RMQQAG60xjl82KRExbkaBVCknmY+-oEhmog8fgHBIBHwCDm5J94W8jfn91cI2ZjYAB0wP46T4wMBlDBjFeUAA9HCojQaIoaABCDiQBKjKBgFGQGigZz2ITufg0aCSJTkMD8YA4ShBCCAlinCx4L53S5Pf7gkFMfIIxL9fggDBAA)