How to Automatically Infer Types in a TypeScript Functional Pipeline Using Higher-Order Transformer Functions?
I am building a simulator where an object is transformed step by step through various functions using pipe from fp-ts. To make the code more expressive, I'm using higher-order functions to create these transformers.
Here's an example of what I want my code to look like:
pipe(
    { name: "Nick" }, 
    merge({ age: 34 }), 
    merge({ job: "programmer" }), 
    merge({ married: true })
);

Ideally, I want this to be type-safe by specifying types for pipe, as shown below:
type Guy = { name: string };
type GuyWithAge = Guy & { age: number };
type GuyWithAgeAndJob = GuyWithAge & { job: string };
type GuyWithAgeAndJobAndMarried = GuyWithAgeAndJob & { married: boolean };

pipe<Guy, GuyWithAge, GuyWithAgeAndJob, GuyWithAgeAndJobAndMarried>(
    { name: "Nick" },
    merge({ age: 34 }), 
    merge({ job: "programmer" }), 
    merge({ married: true })
);

// results in { name: "Nick", age: 34, job: "programmer", married: true }


I want TypeScript to infer the types at each step, such that it only accepts the difference between the types, ensuring that the object transformation is type-safe.
I managed to implement this with generics and TypeScript utilities, but there's a caveat:
// Merge is like A & B but it overwrites properties on A with B. Like {...A, ...B}
type Merge<First extends object, Second extends object> = Omit<
  First,
  keyof Second
> &
  Second;

// A delta is the object that you merge with From to create To
export type Delta<From extends object, To extends object> = {
  [K in keyof To as K extends keyof From
    ? To[K] extends From[K]
      ? never
      : K
    : K]: To[K];
};

const merge =
  <First extends object, Second extends object>(
    delta: Delta<First, Second>,
  ) =>
  (obj: First): Merge<First, Delta<First, Second>> => {
    const merged = {
      ...obj,
      ...delta,
    };
    return merged;
  };

type Guy = { name: string };
type GuyWithAge = Guy & { age: number };
type GuyWithAgeAndJob = GuyWithAge & { job: string };
type GuyWithAgeAndJobAndMarried = GuyWithAgeAndJob & { married: boolean };

const guy = pipe<Guy, GuyWithAge, GuyWithAgeAndJob, GuyWithAgeAndJobAndMarried>(
  { name: "Nick" },
  merge<Guy, GuyWithAge>({ age: 34 }),
  merge<GuyWithAge, GuyWithAgeAndJob>({ job: "programmer" }),
  merge<GuyWithAgeAndJob, GuyWithAgeAndJobAndMarried>({ married: true })
);

The issue is that I need to explicitly specify the types each time I call merge, which leads to verbosity.
My question is: Is there any way to get TypeScript to automatically infer the correct generics for each merge call within the pipe, so that I don't have to manually specify the types at each step?
Edit
I’ve broken down the issue further. pipe expects a function of type A => B. When I pass merge<First, Second>(delta), it returns (obj: First) => Merge<First, Delta<First, Second>>.
This means I’m providing pipe with (obj: First) => Merge<First, Delta<First, Second>>, where it expects A => B. Thus, A should map to First, and B should map to Merge<First, Delta<First, Second>>, which ideally simplifies to Second (but perhaps this simplification is incorrect?).
I’m trying to understand why TypeScript can’t infer that A corresponds to First and B corresponds to Second, which would eliminate the need to pass generics to merge. My aim is to understand TypeScript’s inference mechanism better and/or fix the code so that the inference works as expected.

I can get pipe to result in Merge<object, { married: boolean }> but not GuyWithAgeAndJobAndMarried with type InvokeResult<First, Fn> = Fn extends (first: First) => infer Second ? Second extends object ? Second : never : never and
type PipeResult<First, Fns> = Fns extends [infer Fn, ...infer Rest] ? PipeResult<InvokeResult<First, Fn>, Rest> : First

Your merge() function doesn't have any place from which to infer First or Second, since it can't invert the Delta type to get its pair of inputs from the output. Instead I'd suggest making merge() generic directly in its inputs, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@Caleth do you mind sharing a playground link to show how those types are implemented?

@jcalz yeah you're right about Delta. I was hoping that typescript would somehow be able to still infer First/Second from somewhere else, but I wasn't sure how. Your solution is pretty good - it allows extra properties to be passed into merge, but that's not a huge deal. I guess there's no perfect solution?

I just have pipe casting to PipeResult: playground

"Extra" properties meaning what? Without a [mre] demonstrating what you consider the imperfection, I have no idea. –

@jcalz I just mean in your playground I can add more properties to each argument passed to merge. For example change merge({age: 34}) to ({age: 34, extraproperty: true}), and I don't get an error. Here's a playground with my code so you can compare. In my example, I do get an error by adding extra properties to merge, as I would expect.

@Caleth My goal is to eliminate (infer) the types being passed to merge(), not to pipe(). See my playground in my comment to jcalz. I am able to delete the types passed to pipe but not to each merge call.

Extra properties aren't type errors, though. It's hard for me to envision why you want a type error there, especially if you don't want to manually write out the types GuyWithAge and GuyWithAgeAndJob everywhere. If you do want to write out those types then you're free to do so, it's just a slightly different type. So is this still not "perfect" or should I proceed?

@jcalz I like having the "Object literal does not allow extra properties" error here. I'm trying to use the types as the source of truth for the structure of the object, and I don't want it to be easy to add extra properties directly in merge(). I do get why I shouldn't make a huge deal about this, but is it possible to accommodate this request? I am able to get it working in my playground link, but it feels redundant that I have to supply the types to merge, because they are already supplied to pipe.

@jcalz The essence of my question is this: If you look at my playground link, it feels redundant that I still have to pass types to merge even though I'm already passing them to pipe. I'm currently trying to work out why I think that should be possible - maybe it's an error in my thinking or in how typescript works.

Excess properties are not type errors; they only get warned about in specific circumstances, and it’s almost certainly more trouble than it’s worth to make it so that you supply the types exactly and only where you’d like it. Could you look at this and say what the issue is? Why is it better to have four type arguments on pipe and not one type argument on each merge? I’m really struggling to understand why there’s a problem in my solution. TS doesn’t have “exact types” and nothing you do will guarantee that excess properties are not present.

(see prev comment) I mean, if I play around with the types, I settle on something like this, which seems to be about as good as I can imagine having with TypeScript. You either don't specify types, in which case you get everything inferred for you, or you specify type arguments for merge so that nothing extra sneaks in, unless of course something does sneak in, which is always possible.  This is a feature of TS, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/75721666/2887218, and it's hard to do anything general about it.

@jcalz I would rather describe the types in pipe rather than in merge since I plan on using pipe types as the source of truth for the whole flow. Also, I'd rather abstract Delta away inside of merge rather than pass it into each merge. But thanks for these solutions. I suspect these tradeoffs must happen, so these will definitely come in handy. Could you check my latest edit to see if there is any possible solution here?

Are you okay just asserting that Merge<First, Delta<First, Second>> is Second, as shown in this playground link? That should clear up the inference enough for it to work.

@jcalz That sure seems promising! I've been trained to balk at all type assertions, but I know experts say there's a time and a place for them. I would be interested in knowing if there are any scenarios in which this would fail, and why exactly the type assertion is required here.

Right now you're expecting TypesScript to be able to match a type like (arg: Guy) => GuyWithAge to the type <F, S>(d: Delta<F, S>) => (o: F) => Merge<F, Delta<F, S>> called on a value of type {age: number} and from this, infer F and S to be Guy and GuyWithAge respectively. This is too much for TypeScript to do. While F appears fairly straightforwardly in that type, the S type is buried within both Delta and Merge, which are implemented with conditional types.
TypeScript's inference works best when the types you need to infer are very directly related to the types it has to work with.  As a first step here, I'd say that if you expect Merge<F, Delta<F, S>> to always be equivalent to S, then you should probably just use the type <F, S>(d: Delta<F, S>) => (o: F) => S directly, and that will give TypeScript more of a chance to infer S properly:
const merge =
  <F extends object, S extends object>(
    delta: Delta<F, S>,
  ) =>
    (obj: F): S => {
      const merged = {
        ...obj,
        ...delta,
      };
      return merged as any; // <-- just assert this
    };

Yes, we need to assert that {...obj, ...delta} produces a value of type S, because TypeScript can't follow how Omit and Delta work for arbitrary generic types. This is basically the missing feature described at microsoft/TypeScript#28884. There are edge cases in which Merge<F, Delta<F, S>> and S are not equivalent (e.g., when S is a callable type) but I'm not going to worry about those here; I'd advise not worrying about them until and unless they show up in use cases you care about.
Anyway, once we make that change then you get the inference you're looking for:
type Guy = { name: string };
type GuyWithAge = Guy & { age: number };
type GuyWithAgeAndJob = GuyWithAge & { job: string };
type GuyWithAgeAndJobAndMarried = GuyWithAgeAndJob & { married: boolean };    
const guy = pipe<Guy, GuyWithAge, GuyWithAgeAndJob, GuyWithAgeAndJobAndMarried>(
  { name: "Nick" },
  merge(({ age: 34 })), // okay
  merge({ job: "programmer" }), // okay
  merge({ married: true }) // okay
);


That's the answer to the question as asked, and it meets the needs of the person asking the question.  Future readers may have different use cases:
Having merge() require F and S up front when you call it only giving it a value of type Delta<F, S> is limiting, since it makes inference very difficult.  If you call merge({a: 123}) independently of pipe(), you'll currently get a type like (x: object) => object, which isn't useful. More useful in general would be to have the function be directly generic in the type of its input, and have the returned function be directly generic in the type of its input. This makes inference and control flow work together instead of fighting with each other:
const merge =
  <U extends object>(delta: U) =>
    <T extends object>(obj: T) => {
      const merged = { ...obj, ...delta };
      return merged as Merge<T, U>;
    };

Now TypeScript would only need to infer from the call sites directly.  If you call merge({a: 123}) you get a return type of <T extends object>(obj: T) => Merge<T, {a: number}>, which lets you re-use that multiple times and get multiple outputs.  And then when you call pipe() you don't need to specify types manually at all:
const x = pipe(
  { a: 123 },
  merge({ b: "xyz" }),
  merge({ c: true }),
  merge({ d: new Date() })
)
/* const x: {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: boolean;
  d: Date;
} */

If you do want to manually specify types, you can, but it's not necessary. And again, the asker of this question doesn't apparently care about this use case, and is much more concerned about excess property checking, which only happens in some circumstances in TypeScript and is quite fragile, see
Enforce type checking for object created by spreading. For future readers, however, there may be some benefit in the more direct types shown here.
Playground link to code

Good point on Merge<F, Delta<F, S>> not being equal to S when it's callable. I was wondering what those edge cases could be. Great thorough answer!
